# How to load a file from google cloud storage to google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have to read data from a file which is stored in google cloud storage  am using this method to load file inside my GCP function but this is causing error

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('bulk-testing')
blob = bucket.get_blob("h1.csv")
blob.download_to_filename("h2")
```

Error:- download_to_filename loads files with 'wb' mode 
Error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'h2'

This function is not running in a local machine/environment so there is no way i can download file on local machine and then open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to write a file in Cloud Functions, the only writable part of the system is in /tmp.  [Read the documentation about this.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system)  This space is backed by memory, so you will need to make sure that the function has been configured with enough memory to write the file.

You should probably call out the full path of the file to write:

```
blob.download_to_filename("/tmp/h2")
```

Comment: worked for me thanks, one more question can i write in h2  too  or i can just read from it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  You can do whatever you want with this file.

Comment: how i can remove this file from memory (/tmp/h2)

Comment: This is a separate question (and you should be able to find lots of answers for it already). But something like from pathlib import Path; Path("tmp/h2").unlink() should work

Comment: If you have a separate question, then please post it separately rather than adding comments.